# ionic, php server, mysql database, and rest api

Tags: php, mysql, rest, ionic-framework, server

i'm new to ionic and restful api, and i have to make a mobile app that uses these technologies and a server that uses php. Does anyone have any idea about how the rest api should look like and the server too or any example that can help... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

REST asks developers to use HTTP methods explicitly and in a way that's consistent with the protocol definition. This basic REST design principle establishes a one-to-one mapping between create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) operations and HTTP methods. According to this mapping:
To create a resource on the server, use POST.
To retrieve a resource, use GET.
To change the state of a resource or to update it, use PUT.
To remove or delete a resource, use DELETE.

a simple php rest api file would look like this:

```
<?php 

if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
echo "The id is".$_GET['id'];
}else if(isset($_GET['name'])

{
    echo "The name".$_GET['name'];

}else if(isset($_POST['username']))

{
    echo "the user_name is".$_POST['username'];

}

?>
```

saving this file as  "api.php"

sending a get request with parameters would be like this:

```
http://localhost/api.php?id=5;
http://localhost/api.php?name=henry;
```

a post link woud look like

```
http://localhost/api.php
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup your MySQL database on your PHP server (create database and tables). You can then get a fully working PHP restful API by uploading and configuring `api.php` from https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api (see the README for details). It is then up to you to implement the Ionic application that communicates with the API (disclaimer: I'm the author of PHP-CRUD-API).